# Is Auto-renewable Subscription latest_receipt_info array order reversed in MacOS?

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, subscription

The code of Auto-renewable Subscription works fine iOS, I copy the same code to Mac Cocoa for testing in a new app(sandbox). The purchase process also works fine, but problem happens when it's expired and I try to restore purchased, it always give the oldest transaction but not the latest.

In iOS, `receipInfo.lastObject` gives the latest correct one

In MacOS, the latest one is the first one of the array, `receipInfo.firstObject`

This should not be different, since both iOS and MacOs use the same StoreKit, but just have no idea why this happens.

```
do {
        let requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        let storeURL = URL(string: verifyReceiptURL)!
        var storeRequest = URLRequest(url: storeURL)
        storeRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        storeRequest.httpBody = requestData
                
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        let task = session.dataTask(with: storeRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data , error == nil {
                do {
                    let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)
                            
                     guard let receiptInfo: NSArray = jsonResponse["latest_receipt_info"] as? NSArray else {
                         return
                     }
                     debugPrint(receiptInfo)
                     let info = receiptInfo.lastObject
                     ......
                            
                } catch let parseError {
                    print(parseError)
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
     } catch let parseError {
         print(parseError)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found in iOS the latest is first in the array. In my app I had it set to check the last item in the array and it was returning old data.